# How much does it cost to travel with the compass?

Tags: altos-odyssey

In the Workshop, there is a Compass on sale for 4,000 coins with the following description:

> Found hidden in the Temples, this compass allows you to travel to the biome of your choice **for a small fee**.

The description doesn’t clarify how much “a small fee” is, which makes me think I should consider spending my coins somewhere else.

**How much does it cost to travel to a new biome with the Compass?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That “small fee” is actually 1000 gold per use.